# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

I have a problem with request I make to an api and I want a json return like this:

```json
{
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        User,
        ...
    ],
    "pager": {
        "current": integer,
        "total": integer
    }
}
```

it's a list of user in my db.

I use postman and I can't realy understand the problem I try to find a solution with google but nothing concrete. So I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public function getListUser(Request $request)
{

    $pseudo = $request["pseudo"];
    $perpage = $request["perpage"];
    $users = User
         ::select('username','pseudo','id','email')
         ->where('pseudo','LIKE',$pseudo.'%')
         ->paginate($perpage);

    return response()->json([
            'message'=>'OK',
            'data'=>$users->items(),
            'current'=>$users->currentPage(),
            'total' => $users->lastpage()
            ]
     ,200);
}
```

I try to get the params:

[image]

Comment: Request is not an array, what are you trying access from the request?

Comment: Don't use the facade. Use `Illuminate\Http\Request`. This implements `ArrayAccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Input Facade`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get) get Method

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;


$pseudo = Input::get('pseudo');
$perpage = Input::get('perpage');
```

Comment: This is wholly unnecessary since op already has an instance of request.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get query params incorrectly. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input):

> ## Retrieving Input From The Query String
>
> While the input method retrieves values from entire request payload
>   (including the query string), the `query` method will only retrieve
>   values from the query string:
>
> ```
> $name = $request->query('name');
> ```

Try this way:

```
$pseudo = $request->query('pseudo');
$perpage = $request->query('perpage');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to access your request parameters as an array you need to change:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

To:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

If you cannot stop using the facade, an alternative would be to use `instance`. You will no longer need the argument:

```
public function getListUser()
{
    $request = Request::instance();
    $pseudo = $request["pseudo"];
    $perpage = $request["perpage"];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$pseudo = $request->pseudo;
$perpage = $request->perpage;
```